# How to have a different password for Facebook and Facebook messenger?

Tags: facebook-messenger

I have an Android phone.

I want to use Facebook messenger as IM.

But I don't trust my Android phone enough to give it my Facebook password.

**Q:** Is there any option to set a different password for Facebook Messenger?

Comment: I don't think this could be possible since Messenger is an extension of Facebook, hence it  uses your Facebook credentials.

Answer (score -2):

Yes.  I have the messenger app on my phone.  When I log in, I use my phone number and a password.  When I log into Facebook I use my email and a different password.

Comment: Hi, it's interesting to know that you seem to have 2 different passwords for the same account, but unfortunately, you didn't explain how to achieve that, and we're now curious...